# Control docker daemon

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, docker, daemon

I had observe on the same OS (ubuntu 16.04), different machines, that if I run `sudo systemctl status docker`, then I have different results concerning the location of docker.service, more exactly on one machine I have:

```
   docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
      Active: active (running) 
....
      CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
              ├─1411 /usr/bin/dockerd -H unix://
```

and on the other machine I have:

```
   docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
      Active: active (running) 
....
      CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
              ├─1411 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
```

What is the cause for different location of docker.service ? Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default configuration file for the docker daemon is located in `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`, while custom configuration can be placed in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` or in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/` folder, which overrides the default.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473687/how-to-change-dockerd-parameters-with-systemd) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784295/setting-dns-for-docker-daemon-on-os-with-systemd).

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/v1.10/engine/admin/systemd/):

> There are a number of ways to configure the daemon flags and environment variables for your Docker daemon.
>
> The recommended way is to use a systemd drop-in file. These are local files in the `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d` directory. This could also be `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service`, which also works for overriding the defaults from `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`.

Note, that this is from an old version, that section changed in [current version](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/)  saying the following:

> The recommended way is to use the platform-independent daemon.json file